# Setup Multiple SQL Server Tree Structure similar as RDC based on Enviornments

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I want to setup multiple SQL Servers like a tree structure similar to Remote Desktop connection Manager, where we can setup multiple servers based on environments we support like Test and Prod.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a feature of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) called Registered Servers.  Access the feature by going to "View" -> "Registered Servers."

You can then right-click on "Local Server Groups" and choose "New Server Group" to create the top-level containers ("TEST_ENV1", "TEST_ENV2").

You can right-click on those containers and choose "New Server Registrations" to add instances to that group ("SQL_SERVER_1", "SQL_SERVER_2").

There's lots of information about this feature on the Microsoft Docs site here: [Register Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/register-servers?view=sql-server-2017)

> ### Benefits of Registered Servers
>
> With Registered Servers you can:
>
> - Register servers to preserve the connection information.
> - ...
> - Create groups of servers.
> - Provide user-friendly names for registered servers by providing a value in the Registered server name box that is different from the Server name list.

You can also share these registrations, either by exporting them, or by [creating a Central Management Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/create-a-central-management-server-and-server-group?view=sql-server-2017).